# NSIS: How to manually extract files during installation

Tags: installation, compression, nsis

I have a rather large project whose Installer is written using NSIS.
My problem is, that I cannot simply add all files to the installer file, because it will exceed the 2GB limit.
I also cannot leave my large files in a flat structure on the dvd and just copy them using the `CopyFiles` command, because the total size of the directory structure will exceed 4.7GB.

So what I want to do now is to have my big files in a flat but compressed structure on the dvd and manually extract them to the install directory during installation. The structure on the dvd would look like this:

```
/ 
+--+ data
|  +-- <compressed files>
+--setup.exe
```

Are there any convenient ways of doing this?

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas.

Comment: did you try [unzipping](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Nsisunz_plug-in) the files on run-time, using `nsisunz::Unzip "$DVD_ROOT\data\myzipfile.zip" "$INSTDIR"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- There are several NSIS plugins that can extract from external archives: [ZipDLL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ZipDLL_plug-in), [NsUnzip](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsUnzip_plugin), [ExtractDLLEx](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExtractDLLEx_plug-in), [ExtractDLL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExtractDLL_plug-in), [CABSetup](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CABSetup_plug-in) or [UnTGZ](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UnTGZ_plug-in)
- You could execute a external tool like UnRAR.exe or 7z.exe
- You could create some mini NSIS installers that you execute (Run with /D to set $instdir for sub-installers, you probably want to use `/S /D=$instdir`)